# Android Studio AsyncTask get Result to other Activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an Activity where I want to show my received date from a Database.
Showing my result in a TextView, that's no problem. But I also want to save my received Data in an String value.
My Code:
Main Activity:

```
db3 = new DatabaseC529(C529chooseActivity.this,tvC529Cthirdoccupied,tInt3);
db3.execute(methode, date, timeId3);
```

DatabaseC529:
Constructor:

```
public DatabaseC529(Activity activity, TextView textView, String myValue){  
        this.activity = activity;
        this.ctx = activity;
        this.textView = textView;
        this.myValue = myValue;}
```

...

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {super.onPostExecute(result);
this.textView.setText(result);
this.myValue = result;
 }
```

After AsyncTask is completed, the Result is shown in the TextView.
But I also want to have the Value stored in my String "tInt3".
I created a button (just to check if the Value is stored) to get the content of tInt3 after AsyncTask is completed, but it always shows "null".
Code Button:

```
public void button1 (View view){if(view.getId() == R.id.button1){
        Toast.makeText(this, " " +tInt3, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Can somebody please help me???

Comment: where are you storing value to tInt3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Comment: Thank you guys, creating an interface solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to store your string data and then use it.

Saving values:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(yourpref, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("tInt3", Result);
 editor.apply();
```

Getting Values:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(yourpref, MODE_PRIVATE);
 String value= prefs.getString("tInt3", "null");
```